# How co-linearity affects the value of $\beta$?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multicollinearity

if I have a simple linear model with 1 predictor

$y = \beta*x $

imagine that $\beta$ is 0.5

now I have 2 variables which are correlated

$y = \beta_{1} * x_{1} + \beta_{2} * x_{2}$

My manager told me that $\beta_{1}$ and $\beta_{2}$ will be bigger, "because they try to fit the outliers"

I don't understand why/how the second model will focus more on outliers.

Could anyone give me some insight here?

Thanks

Comment: What your manager said is, as you suspect, not correct.  What is true is that  each parameter in the model with the correlated predictors is less precisely estimated due to the correlation.  This simply means that the variance of the parameter estimates in the second model will be larger.  The magnitude of the parameter estimates themselves will not be larger (in fact, smaller, because they do not have to account for all the variation of $y$ alone).

Comment: The other side to the coin is that if you do leave out predictors (e.g. by using just one) then your parameters are "biased". i.e. They are larger as they **do** have to account for all the variation of *y* alone.

Comment: Good point @JeremyVoisey.

Answer (score 2):

There is no general rule as to how the parameter estimates will be affected by adding a colinear variable.  But you can easily run examples with outliers that show various effects.

```
set.seed(1234)   #sets a seed

x1 <- c(rnorm(1000), 10)
x2 <- x1*5 + rnorm(1001, 0, 0.1)
y <- x1 + x2 + rnorm(1001,0, 2)

m1 <- lm(y~x1 + x2)
m1$coefficients #0.09, -1.73, 1.53

m2 <- lm(y~x1)
m2$coefficients #0.09, 5.93

m3 <- lm(y~x2)
m3$coefficients #0.08, 1.19
```

So, in this particular case, adding x2 to the model with only x1 made the coefficient for x1 switch sign and get farther from 0, while adding x1 to the model with only x2 made the coefficient for x2 a bit smaller.

With colinear data, it is common to get bizarre coefficients with huge standard errors.